# Trying to color all occurrences of a textview string

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, swift2

I'm trying to color all occurrences (not just the first) of a textview string however when I get to the looping I get a cannot invoke `rangeOfString` argument.

I checked the `rangeOfString:options:range` documentation on Swift 2 and it looked pretty similar. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    func textView(textView: UITextView){

        if textView == self.textView {

            let nsString = textView.text as NSString
            let stringLength = textView.text.characters.count

            var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: textView.text.characters.count)

            let searchString = textView.text

            let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
            text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))

            textView.attributedText = text

            while(range.location != NSNotFound) {

                range = (textView.text as NSString).rangeOfString(searchString, options: NSStringCompareOptions, range: range)

                text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: nsString.rangeOfString("hello"))
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(range.location != NSNotFound)` then you didn't change value of `range`. So infinite loop for sure.

Comment: You need to modify the loop so it moves through the string, and you should update the text onto the view after all modifications are done. You also seem to be getting confused with the different strings you have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to highlight user input from search bar. Here how I do so:

```
func highlightedText(text: NSString, inText: NSString, var withColor: UIColor?) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:inText as String)
    let range = (inText.lowercaseString as NSString).rangeOfString(text.lowercaseString as String)
    if withColor == nil {
        if let color = globalTint() {
            withColor = color
        } else {
            withColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: withColor! , range: range)
    return attributedString
}
...
textView.attributedText = highlightedText("string", inText: titleText, color: nil)
```